# Tengo problemas marcados en mi codigo typescript no tengo idea a que se debe

Tags: javascript, typescript, vscode

me aparecen unos errores en vs code al momento de escribir un clase en typescript:

```
interface User{
    name: string
    userName: string
    id: number
    date: object
    UserInfoObject()
    RegisterUserData(info: object)

}
let db : any[] = []
class User implements User{
    name: string
    userName: string
    id: number
    date: object
    constructor(name: string, userName: string, id: number, date: object = new Date()){
        this.name = name
        this.userName = userName
        this.id = id
        this.date = date
    }
    UserInfoObject(){
        return {id: this.id, name: this.name, userName: this.userName, date: this.date }
    }
    RegisterUserData(info?: object){
        db.push(info || this.UserInfoObject())
    }
}

class premiumUser extends User{
    premium: boolean
    constructor(name: string, userName: string, id:number, date:Object = new Date(), premium: boolean = true){
        super(name,userName,id,date)
        this.premium = premium
    }
    PremiumUserInfo(){
        return {id: this.id, name: this.name, userName: this.userName, date: this.date, premium: this.premium}
    }
    RegisterUserData(){
        super.RegisterUserData(this.PremiumUserInfo())
    }
}

const jose = new premiumUser("jose","jose2018",1)
jose.RegisterUserData()
const victor = new User("victor", "victorl", 2)
victor.RegisterUserData()
```

problemas que aparecen:

[image: problemas]

a que se debe esto? transpila mi codigo sin ningun problema y funciona como deberia de hacerlo. gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Tienes tanto una interfaz como una clase llamada `User`, algo que no es valido.

Intenta utilizando la nomenclatura `I` donde todas las interfaces comienzan con la letra `I` y asi sabras cual es una interfaz y cual no. Renombra la interfaz a `IUser`.

En cuanto al error de ambito de variable `db` y `jose`. Esto lo que quiere decir es que no puedes declarar una variable fuera de una clase. Aunque es valido en javascript, esto no lo es en TypeScript:

```
var db : any; // invalido, debe de estar dentro de una clase
class MiClase{

   nombre : any; // valido, esta declarada dentro de una clase
}
```

Comment: Hola. No sabía que no se podía declarar una interfaz con el mismo nombre que una clase (creí que sí porque la clase es un objeto y la interfaz un tipo, o mejor dicho una interfaz). Tampoco sabía que no se podían declarar variables fuera de clases. ¿Podrías indicar un vínculo a donde afirme esos dos hechos?

Answer (score 0):

Acabo de compilar tu código y no parece haber ningún problema

ver [ejemplo en línea](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20User%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20%20%20userName%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20number%0D%0A%20%20%20%20date%3A%20object%0D%0A%20%20%20%20UserInfoObject()%0D%0A%20%20%20%20RegisterUserData(info%3A%20object)%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Alet%20db%20%3A%20any%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%5D%0D%0Aclass%20User%20implements%20User%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20%20%20userName%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20number%0D%0A%20%20%20%20date%3A%20object%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(name%3A%20string%2C%20userName%3A%20string%2C%20id%3A%20number%2C%20date%3A%20object%20%3D%20new%20Date())%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.name%20%3D%20name%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.userName%20%3D%20userName%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.id%20%3D%20id%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.date%20%3D%20date%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20UserInfoObject()%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7Bid%3A%20this.id%2C%20name%3A%20this.name%2C%20userName%3A%20this.userName%2C%20date%3A%20this.date%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20RegisterUserData(info%3F%3A%20object)%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20db.push(info%20%7C%7C%20this.UserInfoObject())%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20premiumUser%20extends%20User%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20premium%3A%20boolean%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(name%3A%20string%2C%20userName%3A%20string%2C%20id%3Anumber%2C%20date%3AObject%20%3D%20new%20Date()%2C%20premium%3A%20boolean%20%3D%20true)%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super(name%2CuserName%2Cid%2Cdate)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.premium%20%3D%20premium%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20PremiumUserInfo()%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7Bid%3A%20this.id%2C%20name%3A%20this.name%2C%20userName%3A%20this.userName%2C%20date%3A%20this.date%2C%20premium%3A%20this.premium%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20RegisterUserData()%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super.RegisterUserData(this.PremiumUserInfo())%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20jose%20%3D%20new%20premiumUser(%22jose%22%2C%22jose2018%22%2C1)%0D%0Ajose.RegisterUserData()%0D%0Aconst%20victor%20%3D%20new%20User(%22victor%22%2C%20%22victorl%22%2C%202)%0D%0Avictor.RegisterUserData())

Pareciera un problema del compilador (como si estuviera compilando dos veces el mismo código o como si ya estuviera generado el .js y quisiera mezclarlo con el .ts).

Quizás te podamos ayudar si nos indicas qué opciones tiene el VSC, si hay un tsconfig.json y demás configuraciones (también la versión del VSC)

### Transpilar vs ejecutar.

Otro tema importante de aclarar: **Que dé error de tipos el tsc (o el VSC) no significa que el código JS subyacente esté mal o no vaya a funcionar**, Lo único que significa es que según los tipos declarados no puede garantizar que esos tipos sean coherentes en todo el código y/o que alguna de las estructuras usadas está mal escrita, declarada o no lo está.